# Helping 1,000,000 gamers to set up local Minecraft server

Tags: discussion

I've just noticed that this question [How do you make a local (LAN) server in minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133658/how-do-you-make-a-local-lan-server-in-minecraft) has over 1 million views!

I think things like this are worth special announcement, for example StackOverflow did such for exiting Vim question back in 2017 - https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/23/stack-overflow-helping-one-million-developers-exit-vim/ , which inspired this question click-bait title. Btw we probably have less traffic than SO, so it's even bigger achievement!

Is there any other cool questions / answers we all should be proud of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For those curious, [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/1072554/arqade-questions-with-1mill-views) is a list of questions with more than  1,000,000 views on Arqade. The top question is actually a Counter Strike question, which sits at over 2.4 million views:

[How can I get more headshots?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122617/how-can-i-get-more-headshots)

It's also interesting to note that 5 of our 10 questions with 1 million are all for Bethesda games, 2 are Minecraft, 2 are Counter Strike GLobal Offensive, and one of them is for a game I've never even heard of before called Hill Climb Racing:

[Best vehicle for each stage in Hill Climb Racing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128860/best-vehicle-for-each-stage-in-hill-climb-racing)

Comment: Don't worry about never having heard of that game. Its better it stays this way... trust me

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/223800/144891 - Helping 1000000 gamers to deliver a baby ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: @arghtype Thanks, I'm definitely going to read over that when my son is born next month ;)

Comment: Ha, got that 10th spot! _pumps fist_

Answer (score 7):

The sites first question was [What is a good strategy to deal with lots of engineers turtling on the other team?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-is-a-good-strategy-to-deal-with-lots-of-engineers-turtling-on-the-other-tea/29879#29879)  It was asked six minutes and 25 seconds after the private beta for the site began which was on July 7th 2010 at 19:00 UTC.  One week later, the public beta began for the site.  You can see this on the [Area 51 post](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338/gaming) that proposed this site.  I suppose that is something to be proud of? Look how far we've come!

If I did my Data Explorer query right, our oldest question is [How do I move Steam games to a new computer without re-downloading them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12695/how-do-i-move-steam-games-to-a-new-computer-without-re-downloading-them/29879#29879) which predates our first question.  How? Because it was migrated from [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) nearly a year and a half after it was asked on that site (posts retain their original posting date even through migrations).